# iPhone: how to connect social networking sites and retrieving user info

Tags: iphone

hi how to connect to social networking sites(twitter) and retrieving user credencials and posting tweet and viewing number of follower, following etc.can u suggest me.

Comment: You need to be much more specific. We can't write your app for you.

Comment: sorry but i dont know, how to start it so that i am asking you, even my team lead is not supporting me and kicking me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a tutorial describing how to connect to Twitter in an iPhone app using an existing third party library:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/twitter-api-iphone/

I found this with a quick Google search, so you may have already come across it. I've used the library referenced in this tutorial, and it's worked fine in the past.

I agree with Robert. Your question doesn't offer many details. I suggest googling around, trying this tutorial and other ones you come across, and then coming back to SO with more specific questions.

Good luck!

Comment: hi CharlieMezak, thank you, i completed upto connecting to twitter server and getting log in Page and Authenticating user by his credentials, i want to get user info like follower,following... etc. how to deal with this

Comment: You'll need to take a look at the twitter API and figure out how to call specific API methods using the library from the tutorial.